# How can I give argmin and argmin equation number?

Tags: equations, numbering

I want to give common equation number of both of them. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
    \DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax} % thin space, limits underneath in displays
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
\begin{document}
           \[\argmax_{\forall i\in N} \big(\zeta_i\big) \triangleq \zeta{(i^+)}\]
     and                     
             \[\argmin_{\forall i\in N} \big(\zeta_i\big) \triangleq \zeta{(i^-)}\]
\EOD

\end{document}
```

This is my expected sample image. [image]

Comment: could you share as an image of the equation you would like to write?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question for your kind considerations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I suggest you replace both instances of `\[` with  `\begin{equation}` and both instances of `\]` with `\end{equation}`.
- I would also omit all four instances of `\big`. Aside: Do you need the parentheses around `\zeta_i`? I.e., why not just write `\argmax_{\forall i\in N} \zeta_i` and `\argmax_{\forall i\in N} \zeta_i`?
- The macro `\zeta` does not take an argument. Hence, just write `\zeta(i^+)` and `\zeta(i^-)`.

```
\begin{equation}
\argmax_{\forall i\in N} \zeta_i \triangleq \zeta(i^+)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\argmin_{\forall i\in N} \zeta_i \triangleq \zeta(i^-)
\end{equation}
```

---

*Addendum*: The following solution incorporates @campa's suggestion to use a single, centered equation number for both equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max} 
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{14} % just for this example
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\argmax_{\forall i\in N} \zeta_i \triangleq \zeta(i^+)\\
\text{and}\qquad& \\
&\argmin_{\forall i\in N} \zeta_i \triangleq \zeta(i^-)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd go for your answer but embedded in `subequations`. This would provide a "single" number (so to say) for both equations, which seems to be what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Unrelated: how comes that your code has no syntax highlighting?

Comment: @campa - Many thanks for the suggestion to use a single equation number. I will update my answer accordingly. About the absence of syntax highlighting: Please see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8668/5001 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8671/5001. Specifically, I insert the meta directives `<!-- language: lang-none -->` right in front of both code chunks. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working for me.